# onreadystatechange is never getting called

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have created XHR and I am also getting response from server correctly.
But for some reason the callback is not happening. Please help.

```
function uploadDr(){
    var url = "UploadExcelServlet";     
    if (req != null) {
        try {
            req.open("GET", url, true);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
        req.onreadystatechange = callBk;
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        req.send();
    } else {
        alert("Null Request");
    }
}


function callBk(){
    if (req.readyState == 4){
        if (req.status == 200){
            alert(req.responseXml);
        } else {
            alert(req.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the callBk() function not getting called? Or is it getting called but (req.readyState == 4) is false?

Comment: @George It is not getting called. I had an alert as the 1st line still I was not getting it.

Comment: @AbhinandanSahu: Check *Error Console* to see the exact error message.

Comment: There was a duplicate uploadDr() method which was getting called instead (I hate to work on code written by someone else). One issue I am facing after sorting out the core issue is that, I am not able to get the responseText. I am sending an integer 0 or 1 from server which gets printed in logs correctly by I don't get the alert(), for some reason. Hope this is the last piece of the puzzle. Thanks all helping me out here. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For GET requests you *don't* need set the "Content-Type" header, because the data are always passed in the URL.

And maybe you need set request data to send as follows:

```
req.send(null);
```

Then test `readyState` in callback function:

```
function callBk(){
    console.log(req.readyState); // don't stop the script by using alert!
    // other stuff
}
```

Make shure that `readyState` is not equal to `0` (`XMLHttpRequest.UNSENT`).